# how to integrate speech recognition with my app

Tags: android, speech-recognition, integrate

I want to integrate speech recognition in my app.

for example: when user say specific word i put it in code like "hello"
it will capture a picture from my app.
I tried many code put about speech recognition but can't integrate it with my app

1. how to integrate into my app ?
2. how to make specific word to make capture ?

Answer (score 0):

Show speech to text

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtSpeechInput;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        // hide the action bar
        getActionBar().hide();

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Get speech in txtSpeechInput box .

Comment: it's for speech recognition ,, but how to integrate with my project class ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to help you

```
   public class YourClassName RecognitionListener{
    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";



   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);


 speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                "en");

        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
      speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);



}



  @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG+"> "+"onBeginningOfSpeech");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onEndOfSpeech");


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(error);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG+">"+ "FAILED " + errorMessage);
      if(errorMessage.contains("RecognitionService busy"))
      {  speech.stopListening();
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);


      }else if(errorMessage.contains("No speech input")){
          speech.stopListening();
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

        }else if(errorMessage.contains("No match")){
          speech.stopListening();

          speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        }
//        speech.destroy();
//        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String text = "";
        for (String result : matches)
            text += result + "\n";
        if(text.contains("your Keyword here")){
            camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
            Log.v(text+"these are results");

        }

        Log.v(text+"On result");
    }


   @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onEvent");
    }


    public  String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                message = "Audio recording error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                message = "Client side error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                message = "Insufficient permissions";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                message = "Network error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                message = "Network timeout";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                message = "No match";


                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                message = "RecognitionService busy";

                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                message = "error from server";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                message = "No speech input";

                break;
            default:
                message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to import  
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;